# grow selected edged limited to a loop and/or ring

Tags: modeling, edges

blender noob here(a month), was wondering if there is any way(or if there's an addon) to grow a selected edge along a loop or a ring.  this is a feature in 3ds max that i always use.  i know you can create a selection between two selected edges by holding ctrl.  what i'm looking for is a way to grow/shrink the selection along an edge loop or a ring.  Thanks!

EDIT: here's a gif of what i'm talking about:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QwiI.jpg

Comment: I think you might be looking for [Select Next Active](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170657/35559), which is Ctrl-Shift-Numpad+, based on the last selection, and the one before it.

Comment: EDIT. works for ring and loop.  very nice thanks!  i do wish there was a way to select multiple rows of rings or loops like this gif:  https://imgur.com/a/ADG6aR5

Comment: It works with any element, verts, edges, faces, rings or loops, skipped rings or loops, depending on the last 2 elements selected, but only in one direction. I don't know of a tool that will do it in both directions, but on the whole I find this tool much more flexible than 3DS's. Ctrl + / -  expands /contracts in all directions, but that's not what you want. I would recommend exploring all the options in the Header > Select menu.. I've never felt held up by selection in Blender. Blender also makes much more use of H hiding elements to protect them from changes.

Comment: yeah, i actually prefer it going one way so this is nice.  but like being able to grow multiple rows or multiple rings at the same time would probably be good.  all in all i think this is just a case of being too used to one software and now missing some tools that probably weren't as useful to begin with.  thanks for the tip, this helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if I understood you right. Is this, what you are looking for:

You may select an edge-loop by holding down Alt while selecting an edge.
You may select an edge-ring by holding down Ctrl-Alt while selecting an edge.
The same works for face-loops in face selection mode.

Comment: here's a gif of what i mean https://imgur.com/a/ADG6aR5